# HTML/CSS Table selector First/Last/Not ECT

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to combine selector tags?

What I am trying to do is make the first `<td>` inside the first `<tr>` style a certain way I have tried a few ways to try and combine these. Granted the ways i have tried are wrong just looking for points if it is even possible.

Tried this:

```
tr:(:first-child:) td: 
{
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: aqua;
}

tr:(:first-child: td:) 
{
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: aqua;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try like this `tr:first-child td:first-child`  https://jsfiddle.net/Lca2sdta/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple and straight forward. Apply it like below.

**CSS**

```
table tr:first-child td:first-child {
   background:green;
   color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>7</td>
     <td>8</td>
     <td>9</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lca2sdta/)

Comment: I've only just learnt about the selectors getting use to the basics but still thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`tr:first-child` will get the first row `td:first-child` will get the first cell.

So `tr:first-child td:first-child` will get the first cell of the first row.

```css
tr:first-child td:first-child{
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: aqua;
  }
```

```html
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```